# Mongoengine: dynamic Fields with EmbededDocuments as values

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, embedded-documents

I have been using MapField till now as:

```
class Game(EmbeddedDocument):
    iscomplete = BooleanField()
    score = IntField()
    #other not dynamic fields


class Progress(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User, dbref=True)
    games = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField(Game))
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_on = DateTimeField()
```

I need to convert games to a ReferenceField.

I want to create Document with dynamic fields/keys but embeddedDocument as the values, so that I can have a document like:

```
{
    "game1": {
        "iscomplete": true,
        "score": 23,
        },
    "game2": {
        "iscomplete": false,
        "score": 10,
        }
}
```

Is t here anyway I can achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive that using [dynamic document in mongengine](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#dynamic-document-schemas):

> DynamicDocument documents work in the same way as Document but any
>   data / attributes set to them will also be saved

So, you remove the games field, and add later your dynamic field games as, game1, game2, etc fields, they will be saved.

```
class Game(EmbeddedDocument):
    iscomplete = fields.BooleanField()
    score = fields.IntField()    

class Progress(DynamicDocument):
    user = ReferenceField(User, dbref=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField()
    updated_on = DateTimeField()

    p = Progress()
    p.game1 = Game(iscomplete=True, score=10)
    p.game2 = Game(iscomplete=False, score=5)
    p.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Note** - use mongoengine and pandas for below code]

Below code is for read csv file and insert in mongod dynamic collection.

**Example** -: to save csv data in mongod collection dynamically.

```
import mongoengine as me
class DynamicDoc(me.DynamicDocument):
    any_field = me.StringField()
```

```
import pandas as pd

all_csv_records = data_frame.to_dict('records')
data_frame = pd.read_csv(file_path)
for data in all_csv_records:
    report_data = DynamicDoc()
    DynamicDoc.any_field = str('temp_data')
    for col, row in data.iteritems():
        report_data[col] = row
    report_data.save()
```